# Ubuntu 14.04 with Nvidia driver - blank screen after kernel update

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 system on which I installed the 64-bit Nvidia driver (version 343.22) from their website. Everything works fine, however whenever there is a kernel update, after reboot the screen goes blank and I have to re-run the Nvidia installer from console. Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I believe you can install dkms and the headers before you run the installer and it should give you a DKMS option during setup. DKMS will prevent the problem you are experiencing so you don't have to re-install every kernel upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms build-essential linux-headers-generic linux-headers-`uname -r` linux-source
```

Then, run the installer and select the DKMS option when prompted.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is what I need. I'll have to wait until the next update to verify it works, but I remember using it on an older system few years back.

Comment: Had an update today and it works like a charm! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Using the ubuntu package repository. There is a PPA for latest Nvidia drivers if needed: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/ubuntu/x-updates